# WSO2 helm pattern-1 failing with configmaps "apim-conf" already exists

Tags: wso2

I have followed the steps mentioned here: https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/master/helm/pattern-1.  I am encountering an issue that when I execute:

```
helm install --name wso2am ~/git/src/github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/helm/pattern-1/apim-with-analytics
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error: release wso2am failed: configmaps "apim-conf" already exists
```

This happens on the first time of running the helm install command.

I've deleted the configmaps (`kubectl delete configmaps apim-conf`) and the release (`helm del --purge wso2am`), and when I try it again I get the same error.

Any assistance on how to get past this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this is that there was a second copy of the apim-conf.yaml but named apim-conf.yaml_old.  This caused helm to attempt to install apim-conf twice.  This is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the configmaps in the wso2 namespace by using the following command.

> kubectl get configmaps -n wso2

Then you can remove the configmap apim-conf as follows.

> kubectl delete configmap apim-conf -n wso2